# Base-Element in Iframe not considered first when requesting image

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a lib(epub.js) which creates a Iframe for every section in the epub file. These Iframes have a base element, which should change the base location where request are made from.

```
window.onload = function () {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.onload = function(){
    console.log("IT WORKED!!");
  };
  iframe.srcdoc="<html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Title</title><base href='newBase/'></head><body><img src='img.gif' /></body></html>";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};
```

I also build a Git repo: https://github.com/paschty/iframe_base_test

The problem is that the browser ignores the base element and requests a image which does not exist. After the request fails the browser tries with the right URL from the base element and the request succeeds.

The Server says:

```
[Wed Aug 07 2019 10:50:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /sub/img.gif" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Aug 07 2019 10:50:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /sub/newBase/img.gif" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36"
```

This happens in Firefox and Chrome.

I would expect the browser to not try the first request!

Comment: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home

Comment: Seems to be a Firefox Bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1464344